# UWP OPEN-XML-SDK convert document to RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, uwp, openxml-sdk

I have an RTF document in UWP. I use OPEN-XML-SDK to convert it into a Word document, but I also need to convert it into a RichTextBlock. How do I do the last step properly?